# Guide for on-premise SP 2013 & OneDrive

Tags: 2013, onedrive-for-business

I can't find any good how-to about installing SharePoint 2013 on premise with One drive for business on premise too.

Is that something you ever went through ?

For example, do I need 0365 licences in order to use OneDrive ? Even if all keep local ? 
Does this is even possible ?

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OneDrive for Business is supposed to run in the Cloud of Office 365, and you really can’t configure OneDrive and sites links without a subscription. When you navigate to “Configure OneDrive and Sites links” `<CentralAdminURL>/_admin/cloudconfiguration.aspx`, the first information you get is sign up for Office 365. Without it you can’t use OneDrive for business.

[image]

The only thing you can do without a subscription is to use a regular MySite Host Site Collection and configure MySite from your User profile Service Application.

**Update**
Unfortunately Microsfot names your document library in the MySite "OneDrive for Business" which makes it even more confusing. But you can sync the library to a client computer within the same domain.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I just came out with that information. So I just need to set up MySites then ppl will be able to use OneDrive to sync documents

Comment: @Nico True. Here is more to read: [What is OneDrive for Business and what does it do](http://en.share-gate.com/blog/what-is-onedrive-for-business)

Comment: Last year, I tried to set up MySites on existing SP 2013 (no SP1), installation. And I failed :( Do you have a complete walkthrough that could help me ? I mean, do I need specific SQL instance features, specific account, etc. ? Thanks for your help

Comment: @Nico Install SP1 and follow this guide step by step. It's for 2010, but works well for 2013: http://www.harbar.net/articles/sp2010ups.aspx

Comment: Is there any consideration if I plan to use an ARR (located in DMZ) to permit site.intranet, and mysite.intranet to be accessible from outside ?

Comment: Your guide is working perfectly ! Thank you ! User sync is working fine. Now I just need to get same features as ITG External Shareing, but for free ;)